# Plugin to get a result based on form checkbox

Tags: forms

I want to create a page with form submit with 3 fields, for exemple:

Type of door?
[x] stone door [] wood door [] plastic door

and then, in the same page return a text

::there are 5 type of stone doors

someone comes up with way to create it by plugin, or add some code in the functions.php?

Comment: Are you asking us to write code for these functionality?  We can assist you by your code. We can't write code for you here.

Comment: you could use a tabbing plugin for this. eg. gt tabs, wordpress post tabs. not quite a form but the content delivery effect would be instant.